# Using USB NFC reader as native from Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, nfc

I'm testing an Android app that uses NFC. However, my actual testing phone does not have NFC capabilities built-in. What I do have is a USB NFC reader for Windows. Is there a way I can open my app on Android Emulator and link the emulated NFC to my USB NFC reader?

Comment: Unlikely, see: [NFC tag emulation for Android virtual device (AVD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49293691/295004)